# Publish report to Shared folder from C# or through SP(SQL Server 2008)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssis

At high level, this is my requirement. 
We have a windows application, which hosts several report(built using SSRS 2008). Now, we have got a requirement like, whenever the user generates a specific report from the application, the same should be saved in csv format in a shared location.

Of couse, once the report is generated, the users have the provision to save the report in any location they want and in all possible formats as allowed in SSRS 2008,but they feel it is becoming an over head for them. So, they just would like to give necessary inputs to the report through the parameter screen(basically nothing but the small dialog which accepts users input and generate the report) from the windows application and once they click on 'Generate Report' or 'OK' button, they want the report to be stored in a shared location in CSV format with a unique name(format:OrderNumber_DDMMYY, here the order number is unique always. the order number is provided as input through report parameter screen).

We have developed the windows application in VS 2008, now migrated to VS2012 and the backend is SQL Server 2008. We also have a dedicated sharepoint.

Can anyone throw light on the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that might be able to help you.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/699869/Accessing-SSRS-Reports-from-SharePoint-Site-using